# Append to document with Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to append some arbitrary text to the bottom of a document using the Drive SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly using the API, sorry.

You can do it by downloading the file, appending data, and updating it.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Unfortunately my current solution of export-append-update (using text/html as the mime type) totally clobbers all the comments and such. Should I be exporting/importing using another format?